# How to write a Hastable or an Object to the file on Blackberry

Tags: java, serialization, blackberry, object-serialization

I just learned that Blackberry does not support implementing Serializable. So is there any way to write an object (or Hashtable) to a file?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you **have to** write the full object in file?

Comment: No, actually i don't have to.

Comment: Then use JSON-like serialization and store the values in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to store the data, you can use the [PersistentStore](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Creating_a_persistent_store_1253891_11.jsp) to store the item and is the closest thing to Serializable you'll find. Note that this method requires the application to be signed.

Otherwise, you can write the data [to a file on the device](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Writing_text_to_a_file_1219767_11.jsp).

*The linked document also shows how to store it in SQLite or use the two other data stores available.*

Answer (score 0):

Which file? If you're storing some sort of settings object for your app, take a look at the PersistentStore API.